# How to get socket name in javascript

Tags: javascript, python

How would I do the following in javascript?

```
>>> import socket
>>> socket.gethostname()
'LA-DEV-IM-MM'
```

I am using a `gulp` command and I'd like to do something like:

```
if (socket_name in [ip1, ip2, ip3]) {
    mode = dev;
} else {
    mode = prod;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`os.hostname()`](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_hostname).

Note that this API is only available in Node.js. It is not available in the browser environment.